# Unhandled Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, unhandled

I'm currently in the process of learning how to properly do custom exception and I stumbled upon a problem. Whenever I try to utilize an object of a class that throws this custom exception, my IDE's debugger (I'm using IntelliJ idea) says "Unhandled Exception: InsertExceptionName()". The code, in a simplified manner, looks something like this. In this case, it should return an exception if the randomly generated number is <0.5, and return a number otherwise, but it won't do that.
What am I missing?

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x=Math.random();
        operation op=new operation();
        op.execute(x);
   }
}
```

-

```
public class operation {
    public operation() {
    }

    public double execute(double x) throws RandomWeirdException {
        if(x<0.5) {
            throw new RandomWeirdException("<0.5");
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

-

```
public class RandomWeirdException extends Exception{
    public RandomWeirdException() {
        super();
    }
    public RandomWeirdException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What do you mean "return" an exception? When an exception is thrown, it bubbles up the call stack.

You are not handling it in this case. It reaches `main` and thus you have an unhandled exception.

If you want to handle an exception, you'd use a `try-catch` block. Preferably surrounding `main` in this case.

```
try {
    // Code that might throw
    // an exception.
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle it.
}
```

Another solution would be to specify that `main` throws a "`RandomWeirdException`", and not `catch` it in the first place.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RandomWeirdException { ... }
```

It's preferable to just let functions `throw`, unless you can reasonably handle the exceptional case.
If you just `catch` for the sake of catching without doing anything meaningful in an exceptional case, it's the equivalent of hiding an error sometimes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems I didn't really understand the purpose of try-catch blocks until now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `execute` method, without creating a try-catch block for the `RandomWiredException` which it declares that it is throwing. Java required all checked exceptions (that extend `Exception`) to be properly handled by the caller - either with a try-catch block, or by adding `throws` to the calling method (in this case, it is `main`, though, so it shouldn't have a `throws` clause).

So the proper way to do it is like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x=Math.random();
        operation op=new operation();
        try {
            op.execute(x);
        } catch ( RandomWiredException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual code in the catch clause is up to your application's requirements, of course.

Note: use uppercase initial letter when you name classes. This is one of the Java styling conventions that will improve your code readability.

Answer (score 1):

Write **throws Exception** after public static void main(String[] args), then it will work well.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Your code here
  }
}
```